# JPanel's child JPanel is not always repainted with its parent?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, null-layout-manager

I have a class that extends JPanel. When the default constructor of this class is called it will set the JPanel's layout to null. An instance of this class is added to a JFrame which uses a BorderLayout. I then create another instance of this class (this time setting its size and position with setBounds) and add it to my first instance of this class, before adding the first instance to the JFrame. A Thread will periodically call repaint on the JFrame. This works fine until the JFrame is resized to it's minimum size. When I do this no components have their paintComponent method called as would be expected, but when I increase the size of the JFrame only the parent JPanel (the one whose layout is handled by the BorderLayout) has its paintComponent method called. The child JPanel's paintComponent method is not called until the JFrame reaches a considerable size (at least 300x300 pixels). Then oddly enough I can gradually resize the JFrame and both JPanels' paintComponent methods will be called until the JFrame reaches its minimum size again.
So the question is: Why is the paintComponent method of my second JPanel not called everytime it's parent JPanel's paintComponent method is called. This is paintComponent method of the class that extends JPanel, the class the implicated JPanels are instances of:

```
   @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (!scaleValid) {
      scaleWidget();
    }

    if (this instanceof Updatable) {
      ((Updatable) this).onUpdate();
    }

    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(activeImage, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
  }
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Container validation and painting are closely linked to the layout manager API, removing the layout manager will have unwanted side effects, which is why it's normally unrecommended, but without a runnable example, it's impossible to know exactly what's going on..